# Angular custom filter to complex object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a `$scope.users` that I use to show a table and I need to apply a filter with multiple options,

Here is the `$scope.users` object:

```
[
  {
    "login": "andres.un1@mail.com",
    "merchant": {
      "merchantId": 500095,
      "status": "ENABLED",
      "defaultAccountId": null,
      "accounts": {
        "500092": "ADMIN",
        "500178": "CONSULT",
        "500180": "ADMIN",
        "500182": "ADMIN",
        "500201": "ADMIN"
      }
    },    
    "name": "Carlos"    
  },
  {
    "login": "andres.un2@mail.com",
    "merchant": {
      "merchantId": 500095,
      "status": "DISABLED",
      "defaultAccountId": null,
      "accounts": {
        "500092": "CONSULT",
        "500178": "MANAGER",
        "500180": "ADMIN",
        "500182": "ADMIN",
        "500201": "ADMIN"
      }
    },
    "name": "Carlos Andres"
  },
  {
    "login": "cosme.fulanito@mail.com",
    "merchant": {
      "merchantId": 500095,
      "status": "DISABLED",
      "defaultAccountId": null,
      "accounts": {
        "500092": "CONSULT",
        "500178": "MANAGER",
        "500180": "ADMIN",
        "500182": "ADMIN",
        "500201": "ADMIN"
      }
    },
    "name": "Cosme"    
  }
]
```

In the filter I pass other object from the `$scope` to filter the data, in this case is `$scope.searchParams` that I previously calculate in a directive.

`$scope.searchParams`:

```
[
  {'name':'Cosme'},
  {'login':'andres.un1@mail.com'},
  {'status':'ENABLED'},
  {'status':'DISABLED'},
  {'account':'267123'},
  {'account':'543987'},
  {'account':'544111'},
  {'account':'543987'}
]
```

As you can see, `name` and `login` are unique in the filter, but `status` and `account` can have multiple values to apply in the filter. Here is my approach to do that but I think is very ineffective, also is not complete because doesn't have the multiple filter functionality:

```
var secUser = function () {

  return function (input, list) {

    var out = [];

    var nameArr = [],
      loginArr = [],
      statusArr = [],
      profileArr = [],
      accountsArr = [];

    angular.forEach(list, function(filter){
      console.log(filter);
      if(filter.hasOwnProperty('name')){
        nameArr.push(filter.name);
      }
      if(filter.hasOwnProperty('login')){
        loginArr.push(filter.login);
      }
      if(filter.hasOwnProperty('status')){
        statusArr.push(filter.status);
      }
      if(filter.hasOwnProperty('account')){
        accountsArr.push(filter.account);
      }
      if(filter.hasOwnProperty('profile')){
        profileArr.push(filter.profile);
      }
    });

    angular.forEach(input, function(user){

      // no filters applied
      if(nameArr.length < 1 && loginArr.length < 1 &&
        statusArr.length < 1 && accountsArr.length < 1 &&
        profileArr.length < 1){
        out.push(user);
      }
      // filters to be applied
      else{
        if(nameArr.indexOf(user.name) > -1){
          out.push(user);
        }
        if(loginArr.indexOf(user.login) > -1){
          out.push(user);
        }
        if(statusArr.indexOf(user.merchant.status) > -1){
          out.push(user);
        }
      }

    });

    return out;
  };
};
//-- register filter
app.filter('secUser', secUser);
```

Finally here is how I am using the fiter: `<tbody ng-repeat="user in users | secUser:searchParams " class="table-striped">`

¿Is there a better way to implement this filter considering that in the future there can be more filter fields? Also I think is very coupled with the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could do this but one requirement is you need to make your `searchParams` structure more generic. For example, here I'm using an object where each key is the path to the target object and the corresponding value is an array with all the values you want to match against:

```
$scope.searchParams = {
  'name': ['Cosme'],
  'login': ['andres.un1@mail.com'],
  'merchant.status' : ['ENABLED','DISABLED'],
  'merchant.accounts' : ['267123','543987 ','544111','543987'],
}
```

Then you can update your filter to handle generic data. It can't be completely generic because it does depend on your business logic, e.g. does `accounts` match on the key `500092` or the value `CONSULT`. Here is an updated filter function handling the three kinds of targets in your data:

- primitive values match the value e.g. `name`
- arrays match any of the contents e.g. `status`
- objects match any of the keys e.g. `accounts`

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/Lk8jzuyo/) (with data slightly modified for testing)

```
var secUser = function () {
  return function (users, filters) {

    return users.filter(function(user){
      var match = false;

      angular.forEach(filters, function(filterValues, keyPath){
        if (match) return; // if we already found a match, don't continue searching

        // get the target based on the contents of the keypath
        var target = keyPath.split('.').reduce(function(object, key) {
          // get the next part of the path, if exists
          return object && object[key];
        }, user); // initial value is the user object

        if (target !== undefined){ // if the target exists for this item
          var values = []; // stores the values from the item to search against

          if(typeof target === "object") {
            values = Object.keys(target);            
          }
          else if (target.isArray) {
            values = target;
          } else {
            values = [target];
          }

          // check if any entry in values matches any entry of the filter values
          match = values.some(function (v) {
            return filterValues.indexOf(v) >= 0;
          });
        }
      });

      return match;
    });
  };
};
```